# Alfonso Gonzalezs Orbital mechanics simulation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, python, 3d-modeling

I basically copied all the code on Orbital Mechanics Series of Alfonso Gonzalez (because I really don't have any experience with coding, but would like to in the future) on Youtube (for a school project) from videos 1-8. My 3D Plot doesn't look right when I try to simulate the ISS and others' orbit (from video 7). I can't find what's wrong with it, please help me. The code is too long to post here. But in this picture, doesn't show well, but there are just horizontal lines going towards the center when there are supposed to be orbital trails.

[image: simulation attempt based on Orbital Mechanics Series of Alfonso Gonzalez]

Comment: Have you tried asking Alfonso Gonzalez?

Comment: Hi Jerry, feel free to post these types of questions in the videos themselves, I can help out there, and I think that would be the better platform to have this type of discussion. It's great to hear that you're following along with the videos though!

Comment: @AlfonsoGonzalez I think in this case a short answer perhaps listing a few of the enumerable possibilities but reminding that basic code-debugging issues need to be addressed outside of Stack Exchange *then including the body of your comment above* would be great!